# UILabel text alignment not working (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel, anchor

I'm trying to align the text in a UILabel but it's not working. The text prints with the second line of the label hugging the left side of the label. How do I make both lines aligned in the center of the label? Thanks.

```
let bioTextView: UILabel = {
    let tv = UILabel()
    tv.text = "This is sample text for a bio label for a user on this platform."
    tv.backgroundColor = .clear
    tv.textColor = .white
    tv.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    tv.numberOfLines = 0
    tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    return tv
}()
```

Please find the below screenshot for the issue. My requirement is to fit the text in tow lines.

[image]

Comment: use tv.textAlignment = .justified

Comment: Sorry, that still resulted in the second line hugging the left of the label :( thanks though

Comment: @ethan-wilk : tested your code, text seems to be aligned perfectly fine with value .center, what is the issue you are facing? add a screenshot to explain further

Comment: By changing the textAlignment value to .center, you must achieve the output. If you're still facing the problem then a screenshot would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @KeyurTailor Here's a pic of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/crcX9Ah perhaps it's an issue with the anchoring?

Comment: Your link isn’t working, could you try adding the screenshot to your question?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the alignment after you have added the view as a subview.

```
view.addSubview(self.bioTextView)
bioTextView.textAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
let bioTextView: UILabel = {
    let tv = UILabel()
    tv.backgroundColor = .clear
    tv.textColor = .white
    tv.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    tv.numberOfLines = 0

    let textString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: "This is sample text for a bio label for a user on this platform.",
            attributes: [:])
    let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: textString.length)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    textString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: textRange)
    tv.attributedText = textString

    return tv
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using **UIStackView** and has encountered this problem: `stackView.alignment` can ruin `label.textAlignment` property. Simply remove `stackView.alignment`.

Answer (score -1):

Update following line fo code will fix your issue:

```
tv.textAlignment = .center
```

This will align your label text to center.

Comment: Sorry, that still resulted in the second line hugging the left of the label :( thanks though

Comment: check once your label frame

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, say right, checkout your label frame. Can you post image for same?

Comment: @SagarChauhan Here's a pic of the issue: imgur.com/a/crcX9Ah perhaps it's an issue with the anchoring?

Comment: Are you using any custom class of UILabel ?

Comment: @SagarChauhan It's all inside a class of type "DatasourceCell" from the LBTAComponents pod. It's essentially a UITableViewCell.